# How to set InnoDB storage format in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to set the ROW_FORMAT option to DYNAMIC when defining tables using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: You're welcome. Come back when you have a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [mysql specific arguments to `Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#create-table-arguments-including-storage-engines). In your case

```
Table(...,
      mysql_row_format='DYNAMIC')
```

or if using Declarative

```
class Foo(Base):
    ...
    __table_args__ = {
        'mysql_row_format': 'DYNAMIC'
    }
```

But if you're using MariaDB 10.2.2 or later, [DYNAMIC is already the default](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/xtradbinnodb-storage-formats/#dynamic). The same goes for [MySQL 5.7 or later](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format.html).